# parse my json to get values - json sent from Xcode to JS front-end

Tags: javascript, react-native

Trying to parse and read my JSON data.
I am passing my json data from Xcode to my React native front-end.
I have tried JSON.parse and JSON.stringify nothing works.
It always logs "NULL". I need to access the "value"
Help please!!

JSON in Xcode

```
{
  "myDictionary" : {
    "BG" : [
      "{\"value\":\"8 mg\\\/dL\",\"endDate\":635390040,\"startDate\":635390040,\"type\":\"bloodGlucose\"}",
      "{\"value\":\"6 mg\\\/dL\",\"endDate\":635393640,\"startDate\":635393640,\"type\":\"bloodGlucose\"}"
    ]
  }
}
```

JS:

```
const log = HealthkitController.getBloodGlucose()
    .then(result => {
     let res = JSON.parse(result)
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        let final = res[0];        
        console.log(final)         // prints the first object
        let fin = final["value"]
        console.log(fin)           //undefined (doesn't print 8mg/dL)
 }
})
```

result:

```
["{\"value\":\"8 mg\\\/dL\",\"endDate\":635390040,\"startDate\":635390040,\"type\":\"bloodGlucose\"}",
"{\"value\":\"6 mg\\\/dL\",\"endDate\":635393640,\"startDate\":635393640,\"type\":\"bloodGlucose\"}"]
```

Comment: Can you show what actually is inside `result`?

Comment: Please confirm if 'result' is getting the stringified response then only JSON.parse will work. As of now, only BG node contains the stringified objects as elements.

Comment: @DiwakarSingh check question. I added result. I want to access the value.

Comment: Try - JSON.parse(myDictionary.BG[0]).value

Comment: it prints undefined bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is coming back as an Array of strings. If you want to extract the value you can do something like this

```
const values = results.map(result => {
 const { value } = JSON.parse(result);
 return value;
});
```

The output will be:

```
["8 mg/dL", "6 mg/dL"]
```

Answer (score 0):

What does this create?

```js
const log = HealthkitController.getBloodGlucose()
.then(result => {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.lenght; i++{
                let res = JSON.parse(result[i])
                console.log(res) //always null
            }
        });
```

Comment: "result" contains my JSON (check updated question). I want to access the value.

Comment: check my updated code. it prints "undefined"

Comment: yes, because you have walk through the array. Wait 2 minutes, I will fix this.